# Is it possible to enhance white-box cryptography security by homomorphic encryption?

Tags: symmetric, homomorphic-encryption, white-box

Background:

1. Let's discussed based on published symmetric white-box crypto only, such as [Chow's](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-36492-7_17.pdf) [white-box AES](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/71600/any-white-box-cryptography-for-asymmetric-key-what-is-the-latest-status-of-whit).
2. I only know basic concepts/objectives of homomorphic encryption, such as [PHE and FHE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39591/somewhat-homomorphic-encryption-versus-fully-homomorphic-encryption). Bring ciphertext into calculation instead of decryption.
3. Without proper implementation design for real applications, white-box crypto may reveal its own vulnerabilities, such as code lifting (call whole WB function instead of unboxing WB).

Question:

I am thinking (just brainstorm first) how to bring the homomorphic feature into white-box crypto design. For examples:

A1. Use encrypted plaintext P_IN as white-box crypto encryption input to generate encrypted ciphertext C_OUT.

A2. Use encrypted ciphertext C_IN as white-box crypto decryption input to generated encrypted plaintext P_OUT

A3. Treat white-box as an API module. Use encrypted input/output for further calculation steps.

Or

B. Apply homomorphic features on the intermediate values of white-box crypto, in order to prevent cryptoanalysis.

Remark: PHE or FHE supports limited operations (e.g., addition, multiplications), which could be the potential challenges for white-box crypto.

Comment: I like the idea. I hope you will push this further.

Comment: Did you make any progress?

Comment: I see two issues with this general idea: the first is that, with HE, you need something with the private key to be able to decrypt; if that's within the whitebox, then how do you protect that?  The other issue (or, something that HE doesn't automatically address) are fault attacks - the attacker can make minor modifications to the program (which would act like a 'fault') and see how the modified program acts.  Now, that could possibly be addressed, however HE doesn't do that for you for free...